Impossible to fill holes in a blanket implementation?
It seems like a single blanket implementation for some trait prevents more implementations for the same trait with certain generic attributes even if theses attributes are explicitly excluded by trait bounds in the blanket implementation.
To me this feels like a shortcoming of the language that might be avoided. Should a Feature request be posted at the appropriate site ?

General example: using the New Type design pattern and implementing From / Into
you can do:
struct NewType(OldType);
impl<T: Into<OldType>> From<T> for NewType
where
    OldType: From<T>,
{
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        NewType(value.into())
    }
}

To implement all existing Generic variants of From and Into.
But then you can't implement additional Generic Variants to this:
impl From<OtherType> for NewType { ... }

This results in
conflicting implementation for `NewType`


More specific examples:

trying to implement into() for u64 -> f64 either directly (supposedly not a good idea, as both f64 and From are defined externally) or via a NewType struct NewF64 (f64) .
trying to implement into() for Error (NewError) to allow for doing

let e: NewError = "Message".into();


After a lot of research and discussions it seems clear that currently a single blanket implementation prevents more implementations for the same Trait with different Generic attributes.
IMHO this does not ask for any problems and adding multiple implementation - dedicated or blanket - should be allowed. The compiler easily can find actual conflicts: it indeed shows all generic variants of a blanket implementation in appropriate error messages, when a desired one is not in place.

trying to implement into() [...] You should never implement Into. Only From.

No, this is deliberate as it "prevents your code from breaking when there are minor changes (as per RFC#1105) in crates you use", it has already been discussed and this is the solution that was decided.

In fact there seems to be considerations on this:
-> impl specialization #1210

The issue here is not at all about external traits or types. It's all local code.
Only the examples mention the external "From" trait for reason of illustrating.

Neither From nor Into are local to your code. This limitation doesn't exist for purely local traits.

As said From etc is only an example, not the essence of the question (which is only before the first horizontal line)

I wrote a comment in the RFC#1105 thread on Gitgub

As said it's not an issue for local traits at all, and for any external trait the same reasoning as for From applies.

The error message does not suggest that it's a problem that the the trait is external. (obviously there is no external implementation for NewType)
I'll do a test with a local trait ...

(BTW.: Thanks for taking the time for discussing...)

Right, it's not explicitly stated, but it is implied in the "= note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait std::convert::From<i64> for type f64 in future versions" which doesn't hold when either the trait or type is local.

In fact I did an example. But I was not able to exactly reproduce the impl<T: Into<OldType>> From<T> for NewTypepattern but only could manage a trait bound by impl<T: MyTrait<OldType> + MyBound> MyTrait<T> for NewType where    OldType: MyBound, 
Here the problem indeed does not happen.

OK. Seems I was on Error. I did an example with totally local MyFrom and MyInto traits, and in fact the problem does not occur.
Nonetheless, I don't think that the argument that something undesirable should happen, when the external crate is extended is rather faint. in fact some time into() for i64 -> f64 could be provided as standard, but the only thing that will happen is that the compilation results in a totally logical error message.  But in close to every case when somebody extends the functionality of their local New Type, such never will happen.
